# Image shows if condition is met

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide, show

I am making a cookie clicker-esque game and i am making an upgrade bar. One icon starts off invisible and once you have 1 cursor it becomes visible. The problem is it isn't.

I have looked thoroughly and still can't find the bug.
This is in JSFiddle.
Here it is-https://jsfiddle.net/wizviper/mq0qwnvr/
Main Code-

```
document.getElementById("reinforcedFingerShop").addEventListener(cursorAmount >= 1, function() {

if (reinforcedFingerActive = 0) {

  $(this).show();

}

  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

addEventListener listens to events but you are assigning a condition to it "cursorAmount >= 1".
I guess you probably want to know when (cursorAmount >= 1) and also (reinforcedFingerActive == 0), please provide the related part of your code, so that we will be able to help you better

**UPDATE**

You are changing cursorAmount inside "cursorShop" function so the best place to check "reinforcedFingerActive == 0" condition is there.

```
document.getElementById("cursorShop").onclick = function() {
    if (cookies >= cursorPrice) {
      cookies = cookies - cursorPrice;
      cursorPrice = cursorPrice * 1.15;
      cps = cps + 0.1;
      updateValue();
      cursorAmount = cursorAmount + 1;
      if (reinforcedFingerActive == 0) {
        $(this).show();
      }
    }
  }
```

I have not tested but it should work.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for a better way to do it? Should I put it on a looping function?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem come from :

```
if (reinforcedFingerActive = 0) {
```

Maybe did you forgot the second `=` ?

Answer (score 0):

Read official [MDN addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) documentation on how to use this function. First argument is `type`

> A string representing the event type to listen for.

in your code your first argument is `cursorAmount >= 1`